# how to access via absolute path to my application's file - windows phone - Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am porting an application from android to wp8 using Phonegap/Cordova.

This is my source code structure:

[image]

In my **index.html**, I am getting **logo.png** this way (relative path):

```
<img src="img/logo.png" />
```

How to use the absolute path?

I tried in different ways (adding ms-appdata:///local/www/ or ms-app) but with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the org.apache.cordova.file plugin and then you get a variable depending on the OS.

For example, I used (in Javascript using JQuery):

```
$("#myImage").attr("src", cordova.file.dataDirectory + "logo.png");
```

and that specific folder is for read/write files only access for your app. But there is more folders (directories) available.

See here: [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) where it says "Where to Store Files"

If it helped you, mark it as solved, please.

Comment: +1 but I cannot accept this answer because it does not work on wp8, have you tried it?

Comment: in the link says "Supported Platforms" and include Windows Phone 7 and 8... It just says don't support "FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer nor FileWriter.write(blob)" but the rest yes! I haven't try it... have you?

Comment: of course, I have tried it and it doesn't work while it works on android

Answer (score 0):

the absolute path for Windows Phone is "//" !,

```
if( /Android|BlackBerry Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    //android absolute path
    path = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;
} else if (isWindowsPhone) {
    //windows phone absolute path
    path = "//";
} else {
    //iphone absolute path
    path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
}
```